# Registering a stylesheet inside my WordPress widget

Tags: widgets, css, user-registration

I did see the other topic similar to this but I cannot get mine to work.

I am using WordPress 3.8 and am creating a custom widget for a site. I need to style it a certain way so I need to load an external stylesheet.

I have tried:

```
function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'gamestats-style', plugins_url('css/styles.css', __FILE__) ); 

    //Widget content
  }
```

with no luck. I have the css file located in the css directory of my plugin directory "game-stats" so i believe the url is correct.

plugins/game-stats/css/styles.css

if I embed the styles in the php by way of `<script>....styles...</script>` it works fine but this is really bad practice. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please check if the path to the file is correct. You can use tools like FireBug to determine the specified path...

Answer (score 0):

Please check this reference [is_active_widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_widget), check the example for an exact solution. That code will go within the `__construct()` method right after `parent::__construct()` is called. `wp_enqueue_style` works if it is called before `wp_head` is called. and `widget()` method are called definitely after `wp_head` is loaded as it just display the HTML template.

So here is an [example of loading scripts for widget](http://w4dev.com/wp/loading-scripts-for-widget/).